# how to write a custom validator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

please help solve the problem.

models:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  include ActiveModel::Validations

  class FileSizeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
      record.errors.add attribute, "must start with 'the'" unless 1 == 1 # this is test
    end
  end

  validates :video, file_size: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise  :database_authenticatable, 
          :registerable,
          :recoverable, 
          :rememberable, 
          :trackable, 
          :validatable
  has_many :videos
end
```

form:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @video] do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :video %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

video controller:

```
def create   
  if params[:video][:video]
    filename = params[:video][:video].original_filename 
  else
    filename = nil
  end

  @video = current_user.videos.create(filename: filename)
  if @video.save
    flash[:success] = :saved
    redirect_to user_videos_path(current_user)
  else
    flash.now[:error] = :not_saved
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

If I send the form with the filled field 'video', then I get the following error message:

```
Started POST "/users/48/videos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-20 17:33:46 +0300
Processing by VideosController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ukh4iiMQEimDvbOpEtdwTBNeYpdgKZDzepyhnNTWCVRRNx2Xu9v95Wl1iRFp8VDGuDid/BY8ioyedtGbM/imJQ==", "video"=>{"video"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc278691760 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150720-25326-1wrjooo.jpg>, @original_filename="im2.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video[video]\"; filename=\"im2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Video", "user_id"=>"48"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 48]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 32ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `video' for #<Video:0x007fc279389828>):
  app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:25:in `create'
```

If I send the form with the empty field 'video', then I get the following error message:

```
Started POST "/users/48/videos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-20 17:38:31 +0300
Processing by VideosController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kLKGzKQiu6QSFC85EQf0xT5bw0LZcHFxlDb6bcsPlTR7zePRPOlUaPjcFYFqIdRPlT08Ka9law5w3IpqLCE6RQ==", "commit"=>"Create Video", "user_id"=>"48"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:19:in `create'
```

please help write a validator 'file_size'. I used the documentation:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can do something very simple if you just want to run a method

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Notice that it's **validate** without the ending **s**
  validate :video_file_size

  # Notice that it doesn't matter what you return, video will stay valid unless you add an error to the `errors` array
  def video_file_size
    if file_size > 10.megabytes
      errors.add :video_file_size, "Video file size must be less than 10 megabytes"
    end
  end

end
```

This should be enough, without the additional validator class, which is reasonable only if you intend to use it in multiple models.

Comment: please tell me how do I pass the uploaded file size to video_file_size()

Comment: Well, you can find it in `params`! If your file field is named `myfile`, you'll find it as  `params[:myfile].size`. Migrate your `Video` model adding a column `file_size` and ensure you pass in file size when building the object. Simple and effective

Comment: params unfortunately not available in the model: NameError (undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Video:0x007f2054f1f718>):

Comment: You must pass params when building your `Video` object from the controller, `params` not available on model, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `validates <field>, ...` if `field` doesn't exist on your model. If you want to load a validator that runs against the entire model and not a specific field, you need

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_with FileSizeValidator

end
```